# Download file from URL using CURL

Tags: php, curl, download

I try to download file using a php-script from an URL like the following:

```
http://www.xcontest.org/track.php?t=2avxjsv1.igc
```

The code I use looks like the following, but it produces empty download files only:

```
$DLFile= "testfile.igc";
$DLURL="http://www.xcontest.org/track.php?t=2avxjsv1.igc"; 
$fp = fopen ($DLFile, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($DLURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

An other strange thing is when entering the URL in the web browser I don't get the file.  It can I could only download the file when clicking the link on the [web site](http://www.xcontest.org/world/en/flights/detail:pepino/31.10.2012/07:20)!.

Any advice is very appreciated!

Comment: So your code accomplishes the same result as opening the URL in a browser. Sounds to me like your code is OK, and you're asking how to circumvent an anti-hotlinking protection.

Comment: I smell freshly baked cookies :)

Comment: I don't see a policy on their site about direct downloads, but they are preventing hot-linking.

Comment: I was thinking about hot-linking prevention. But I successfully tried to download such a file with a download manager.

Comment: @user1789813 you should contact them about downloading directly, if they say it's ok they should post it somewhere in their terms, otherwise it's probably illegal to circumvent their security, definitely in the USA. [DMCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Give this a go

```
<?php

    $output_filename = "testfile.igc";

    $host = "http://www.xcontest.org/track.php?t=2avxjsv1.igc";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.xcontest.org");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($result); // prints the contents of the collected file before writing..


    // the following lines write the contents to a file in the same directory (provided permissions etc)
    $fp = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

#

or if you want to put it within a loop for parsing several links... you need some functions.. here is a rough idea....

```
<?php

    function collect_file($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.xcontest.org");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return($result);
    }

    function write_to_file($text,$new_filename){
        $fp = fopen($new_filename, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $text);
        fclose($fp);
    }


    // start loop here

    $new_file_name = "testfile.igc";
    $url = "http://www.xcontest.org/track.php?t=2avxjsv1.igc";

    $temp_file_contents = collect_file($url);
    write_to_file($temp_file_contents,$new_file_name)

    // end loop here
?>
```

Comment: The functions I just added at the bottom will help if you are wanting to loop and create several files.. :)

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.xcontest.org"); was what solved it really.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @TheBumpaster The URL you have used may redirect to another page. Set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `true` to solve this.

Comment: Use a built-in `file_put_contents` instead of the custom `write_to_file` function

Comment: After many hours to try ! - this solution works perfectly for upload .zip file from another server setted with the directive allow_url_fopen=0. in the distant server the .zip file is allowed to be donwloaded by link, i write the file in the local server like this: $my_file_uploaded = 'name.zip' $path = '/MY_UPLOAD_TEMP/'.$my_file_uploaded.'.zip'; file_put_contents( $path, $result );

Answer (score 3):

@Chris' answer works, but this seems to work better to download very large files without running out of memory, since it doesn't download the whole file into a variable before writing to disk:

```
$file_url = 'http://www.test.com/images/avatar.png';
$destination_path = "downloads/avatar.png";

$fp = fopen($destination_path, "w+");

$ch = curl_init($file_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec($ch);
$st_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

if($st_code == 200)
 echo 'File downloaded successfully!';
else
 echo 'Error downloading file!';
```

Source: https://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2018/02/php-download-file-from-url-curl.html

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues making the (File Download Dialog Box) show up when using Curl until i did this :

```
// $ch = curl_init();
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
// Other Curl options ....
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if (isset($_POST["downloadExcelFile"])){ 
        // in my code the "downloadExcelFile" field
        // is sent when i'm trying to download an excel file
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="file.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $fp = fopen("php://output", 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $output );
        fclose($fp);
    }
```