# Can't file_get_contents on certain sites (PHP)

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Actually I'm fooling around while developing some things like "change avatar", where there exists the option to get the image from its URL

```
$raw  = file_get_contents($src);
$img  = imagecreatefromstring($raw);
// and others gd stuff
```

Actually it works fine, except when it comes from a certains website, like pixiv
http://i2.pixiv.net/img02/img/suzupin/2800349.jpg 
This, for example, throw some errors

BTW, the same goes when I try to PIN this on Pinterest =P
 WHY?

Is there a way to prevent the others to do things like `file_get_contents` on my site?

 Am I right to say that it has something to do with `oriental websites`? Because pretty often I can't PIN images from japanese sources. >.<

Comment: your link doens't work at all. (403 forbidden)

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus I think he's trying to say that the link _doesn't_ work. And that's the problem.

Comment: kk, I just replaced now. Actually, the links doesn't seens to matter, really. The source (pixiv) still throwing errors, anyway

Comment: `prevent file_get_contents` No, there isn't. You could ban IP address that look suspicious, but `file_get_contents` or `CURL` is just as much as a real request than any other user using their browser to request a resource.

Comment: That one doesn't work either. I think Pixiv is looking for a cookie or referer that we don't have.

Comment: @duskwuff: You are correct. http://www.pixiv.net/ requires registration.

Comment: StackOverflow is scary ò.o It doesn't even passed a minute and I already had some replies ^^

Comment: Look into 'hotlink prevention'. There are many different methods--some @duskwuff suggested--cookies, checking referer, sessions, etc.  It's possible that's what is going on.

Comment: Kah! What a pain. So it means that there's nothing I can do about it? Well, (after some quick read) I think I understand about this "hotlink prevention". Thanks everyone!

Comment: Of course there are work arounds. They just take a little more work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168198/download-file-from-url-using-curl

Comment: @cmt Thank you!! Like, you totally gave me the right answer! It worked really fine. If this was not a comment you had owned my ✓

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted snippets of these comments as an answer so this question can closed. I don't want to waste other people's time by having them attempt to answer a question that you already have a solution to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is these websites are implementing 'hotlink prevention'. There are many different methods--some @duskwuff suggested--cookies, checking referer, sessions, etc.

What you want to do is circumvent hotlink prevention, and that is answered in this SO question: [Download file from URL using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168198/download-file-from-url-using-curl)

Answer (score 0):

You can use login form or captcha then allow image view and test browser version etc. but if user is using curl with cookies (i don't know how to use cookie with file_get_contents then it's tough to disallow user.

Comment: The question is not about how to implement this behavior.

Comment: he asked, `Is there a way to prevent the others to do things like file_get_contents on my site?`  isn't it implement this behavior?

Comment: though the most suited answer for this was `hotlink prevetion`