# Collecting file with PHP CURL after validating request downloads an empty file

Tags: php, curl

I am doing a system where one of my sites goes to the other to get documents.
On the first site I am using Curl to make a request to get the file wanted:
I am using the solution from [Download file from URL using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168198/download-file-from-url-using-curl) :

```
function collect_file($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://example.com");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
        return($result);
    }

    function write_to_file($text,$new_filename){
        $fp = fopen($new_filename, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $text);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    $curlUrl = 'http://site2.com/file-depository/14R4NP8JkoIHwIyjnexSUmyJibdpHs5ZpFs3NLFCxcs54kNhHj';

            $new_file_name = "testfile-new.png";
            $temp_file_contents = collect_file($curlUrl);
            write_to_file($temp_file_contents,$new_file_name);
```

I am testing downloading an image. If i use a direct URL into $curlUrl , for instance http://site2.com/file-depository/image.png it works perfect.

What I am doing is that the URL http://site2.com/file-depository/14R4NP8JkoIHwIyjnexSUmyJibdpHs5ZpFs3NLFCxcs54kNhHj is then parsed and checked against a database to match the document requested, once there is a document matched I need to provide this document to the Curl response.
I have tried many ways to read the file but everytime i am getting a file on the other end but it is only 1kb in size (45 expected) and when trying to open it i get an error unkown file type etc.

On the second site, once the URL is validated here is what I have:

```
$file = readfile('some-image.png');
echo $file;
```

I am guessing there is part of the information which belongs to the file missing but can't figure it out, any pointers appreciated!

Comment: your write_to_file is redundant... just use `file_put_contents()`. did you try loading your "png" file into a text editor to see what REALLY got written out? None of your code even acknowledges the possibility that something might go wrong, which is exactly the WRONG thing to be doing when dealing with external resources.

Comment: I have reduced the code to post to a minimum here to make it as simple as possible to read and I am only testing at this stage, error handling will follow...

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced

```
function write_to_file($text,$new_filename){
    $fp = fopen($new_filename, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $text);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

by file_put_contents($new_file_name,trim($temp_file_contents)); 
Please note the trim(), the issue was that I was apparently collecting some empty space in front of the file content.