# curl download file from remote server

Tags: php, curl, download

I'm trying to download a file from my server via curl. I execute the following code but no file is being downloaded in my computer. I tried to understand how curl works and how should I use the $data that comes when I execute curl but nothing happened. Is there any way to handle the file when it arrives from server?

```
$url  = 'https://xx.xx.xx.xx/test.xml';
$path = './path/to/file/test.xml';

$fp = fopen($path, 'w');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file from URL using CURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168198/download-file-from-url-using-curl)

Comment: I saw this answer but I can not find out how it works. No file in my computer after using this code. How can I see the file?

Comment: Adding some error checking here and there (eg, did fp get initialized correctly, do the curl_setopts succeed and does curl_exec succeed) would be a very useful first step.

Comment: Since this is litteraly the basic curl example from php.net i think the problem might be somewhere else. Are you sure you have write permissions for your file? is the url reachable?

Comment: The url is reachable and the files have all the required permissions.As far as fvu answer, it seems that the curl_exec is not executed successfully.

Comment: Use curl_error (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-error.php).

Comment: @Killan, better use [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) :)

Comment: Ok the problem was with the SSL certificate, I resolved it by adding 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); . The thing is that when I echo $data I can't see the file's content.

Comment: That's because you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to false. [php's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) is very complete and detailed, use it.