# How to check the extension of our file before uploading it to our server with cURL?

Tags: php, file, curl, redirect, file-extension

I am using cURL features to take a file and upload it to my server.  Now I want to check the file extension before uploading it.

**Here is my problem:**

Suppose we have a URL that does not display the file extension in the URL like this one: `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533450718592-29d45635f0a9?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80`

This link sends an image, but in my case, I want to get the extension of this image without uploading it so that I can compare it to the file extensions that are accepted.

**Here is the code that I had used to upload the file in my site:**

```
$url = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533450718592-29d45635f0a9?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80';

function collect_file($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://file-examples.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return($result);
}

function write_to_file($text,$new_filename){
    $fp = fopen($new_filename, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $text);
    fclose($fp);
}


// start loop here

$new_file_name = uniqid() . '.jpeg';

$temp_file_contents = collect_file($url);
write_to_file($temp_file_contents,$new_file_name);
```

**Now I would like to know how can I improve this code to compare the extension to other file extensions that are accepted in my system?** I found this piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168198/download-file-from-url-using-curl).

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP.

**Edit:** Here are the extensions that are accepted: `"jpeg", "docx", "xlsx", "xml", "txt", "pptx", "pdf", "md", "ods", "odp", "odt", "odg", "ots", "ott", "csv", "tsv", "rtf", "resx", "html", "srt", "vtt", "stl", "sbv", "sub", "ass", "dfxp", "ttml".`

I want to check the data formats of these files. HELP ME PLEASE

Comment: Extensions are in filenames. If you don't have a filename, the concept of extension is meaningless. Maybe what you really want to check is the format of the data in the file? If it's an image file, you can use `getimagesize()` to get its metadata.

Comment: @barmar And if it is not an image file, what should I use? And where should I use the function?
Can you show me this in a code block please?

Comment: There's no general solution for arbitrary files.

Comment: I just updated my question.

Comment: @barmar So what do you advise me to do please?

Comment: @barma Can you show me an example with my code regarding the use of this function [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php](mime_content_type) so that I use the function correctly please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a general solution for arbitrary files, but for image files you can use [`getimagesize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). One of the values it returns is one of the `IMAGETYPE_xxx` constants, and it also returns the corresponding MIME type. These correspond to extensions, so you can check these.

```
write_to_file($temp_file_contents,$new_file_name); 
$typedata = getimagesize($new_file_name);
$allowed_types = [IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_BMP];
if ($typedata) {
    $type = $typedata[2];
    if (in_array($type, $allowed_types)) {
        // code to upload the file
    }
}
```

Comment: And for the other files what should I use? I am more interested in the other files.

Comment: As I said, there's no general solution.

Comment: The question says: "This link sends an image"

Comment: This was just for an example.

Comment: But the question was based more on its files "jpeg", "docx", "xlsx", "xml", "txt", "pptx", "pdf", "md", "ods", "odp", "odt", "odg", "ots", "ott", "csv", "tsv", "rtf", "resx", "html", "srt", "vtt", "stl", "sbv", "sub", "ass", "dfxp", "ttml". ```

Comment: For example, there's no way to unambiguously recognize a CSV file. It's a text file that happens to use commas to separate fields.

Comment: You could try using `shell_exec()` to run the `file` command, and parse the output. It uses heuristics to recognize many different file types. I'm not going to try to write it myself.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. Can you help me with the other files too?

Comment: How many ways can I say that there's no simple way to do that?